# WiFi communication between C# and ESP8266

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, windows-forms-designer, esp8266

I'm working on school project right now and I'm looking for the simplest way to connect C# with ESP8266 not via SerialPort (COM4) but via WiFi module on ESP8266 (I have to use this method). I have to build simple project to sending measured data from ESP to C# and also receiving my own defined control commands (strings like "LEDON" "LEDOFF" etc.) from C# to ESP just like remote control of measurement project. I have low knowledge in C# same as basics of servers/internet and things like that. I have everything done in Arduino IDE code but I'm stuck on C# cause I never before programmed there. I hope you understand my bad English and concept of my question. :)

EDIT:

Well, so I did some changes in my school project and now I am on this stage, where I need to solve this part of code. I hope that is last step to finish my project. All I have to do is solve Writing data from C# to ESP using unfilled method named "Writing" in following code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ESP8266
{
    public class Projekt
    {
        public event MessageEventHandler Message;
        public delegate void MessageEventHandler(Projekt sender, string Data);

        public TcpListener server;
        public Thread W_Thread;
        public Thread R_Thread;
        public bool IsLiserning = true;

        public TcpClient client;
        public StreamReader clientdata;
        public StreamWriter serverdata;
        public Projekt()
        {
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName().ToString()).AddressList[1].ToString()), 5000);
            server.Start();

            W_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Writing));
            W_Thread.Start();

            R_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Reading));
            R_Thread.Start();
        }

        public void Reading()
        {
            while (IsLiserning == true)
            {
                if (server.Pending() == true)
                {
                    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    clientdata = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                }
                try
                {
                    Message?.Invoke(this, clientdata.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception){}
            }
        }

        public void Writing()
        {
            while (IsLiserning == true)
            {
                if (server.Pending() == true)
                {
                    client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    serverdata = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                }
                try
                {
                    //NEED_TO_SOLVE_THIS_PART
                }
                catch (Exception){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is missing something more than that part of code and you guys are able to help me I hope :) Thanks for all answers by the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at this [project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884583/Advanced-TCP-Socket-Programming-with-NET), basically you want to communicate via TCP/IP between the arduino and the C#. consider the C# as the server and the arduino as the client. Then they just need to send message to each other to communicate.

The link I'm providing is doing a lot more than needed, so if you're lost, maybe start with something really basic and look [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm) and check the links at the end talking about c# server. They will be easier to understand compared to my first link.

[EDIT] Ok, only links answer is dangerous and not the best, so here is a really light version of what I gave through the first link:

Your server will have a list of receivers, each receiver only handle one client. It's a big simplification of one of my project, I hope that by removing lots of things I didn't break anything:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DemoServer.Models
{
    public class Server
    {
        public TcpListener Listener { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool IsStarted { get; private set; }
        public List<Receiver> Receivers = new List<Receiver>();

        public Server(int port)
        {
            Receivers.Clear();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Receivers, Receivers);
            Port = port;
            IsStarted = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (!IsStarted)
            {
                try
                {
                    Listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0);
                    Listener.Start();
                    IsStarted = true;
                    IPAddress address = ((IPEndPoint)Listener.LocalEndpoint).Address;
                    int port = ((IPEndPoint) Listener.LocalEndpoint).Port;
                    Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
                    //Start Async pattern for accepting new connections
                    WaitForConnection();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    IsStarted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (IsStarted)
            {
                Listener.Stop();
                IsStarted = false;
                Receivers.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Server Stopped");
            }
        }

        private void WaitForConnection()
        {
            Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(ConnectionHandler), null);
        }

        private void ConnectionHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (IsStarted)
            {
                Receiver newClient = new Receiver(Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar), this);
                newClient.Start();
                Receivers.Add(newClient);
                WaitForConnection();
            }
        }

        public void SomeInteractionBetweenClients()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Interaction!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then comes the Receiver code, where you really handle the communication with your client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace DemoServer.Models
{
    public class Receiver : ModelBase
    {
        bool ConnectionStatus = false;

        private uint m_Id = 0;
        public uint Id
        {
            get { return m_Id; }
            set => SetAndRaisePropertyChanged(ref m_Id, value);
        }

        private Thread receivingThread;
        private Thread sendingThread;
        public Server Server { get; set; }
        public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
        public List<String> MessageQueue { get; private set; }


        public Receiver(TcpClient client, Server server)
        {
            MessageQueue = new List<String>();
            Server = server;
            Client = client;
            Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
            Client.SendBufferSize = 1024;
            ConnectionStatus = true;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            receivingThread = new Thread(ReceivingMethod);
            receivingThread.IsBackground = true;
            receivingThread.Start();

            sendingThread = new Thread(SendingMethod);
            sendingThread.IsBackground = true;
            sendingThread.Start();
        }

        private void Disconnect()
        {
            if (!ConnectionStatus) return;
            ConnectionStatus = false;
            Client.Client.Disconnect(false);
            Client.Close();
        }


        private void SendingMethod()
        {
            while (ConnectionStatus)
            {
                if (MessageQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    var message = MessageQueue[0];
                    try
                    {
                        NetworkStream clientStream = Client.GetStream();
                        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(clientStream);
                        streamWriter.Write(message);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        Console.WriteLine($"We are sending '{message}' to the client");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Disconnect();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        MessageQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }

        private void ReceivingMethod()
        {
            while (ConnectionStatus)
            {
                if (Client.Available > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        NetworkStream clientStream = Client.GetStream();
                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(clientStream);
                        char[] puchBuffer = new char[Client.Available];
                        int iQtt = streamReader.Read(puchBuffer, 0, Client.Available);
                        string msg = String.Empty;
                        for (int i = 0; i < puchBuffer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            msg = $"{msg}{Convert.ToString(puchBuffer[i])}";
                        }
                        OnMessageReceived(msg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }

        private void OnMessageReceived(String msg)
        {
            // Here you can parse the messages coming ffrom the client and do whatever is needed
            // If needed, you can even call some public methods from the server to forward some info to an other client for example or just the server:
            // eg: Server.SomeInteractionBetweenClients();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help for the communication part. For the GUI there are lots of tutorials on the web but if possible I still think WPF/MVVM is better to learn than winforms.

Comment: This seems to be helpful source but I need to use WindowsForms, not ConsoleApp :) I'm gonna to try put some lines on my buttons and hopefully it will works :) Thanks

Comment: If you can have a working version using console, adding and interface will be really easy. Tou should always start to work on the functionnality first, UI comes only after.

Comment: Is using winforms mandatory? My first link is using it but honestly winforms is becoming a bit deprecated. If you have the possibility, using wpf (and even better if using mvvm approach) will be more useful in the future. At least it's my point of view ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21426824)

Comment: @Mozahler point taken. I will try to edit my answer today with the more important part of the code.

Comment: @AdamFehér I just edited my answer after Mozahler remark, I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding your project requires 2 way communication. Making c# as server will not be ideal since there is no easy way to send command from C# to esp8266. I assume your project is utilizing esp8266 as the arduino platform (not attaching esp8266 to arduino as wifi module), please check out MQTT which is a broker for publishing and subscribing messages. That way both esp8266 and C# code and communicate via MQTT and achieve 2 way communication purpose.

for esp8266, you can check out arduino MQTT library for esp8266 here: https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient.

Comment: The only problem is that I have to use C# in my school project :/

Comment: you are only adding a middle man (MQTT). You still need C# to communicate with esp, but thru MQTT. I believe this still fulfill your project requirement. And if the requirement insist everything has to be c#, there is c# MQTT broker as well. https://github.com/gnatmq/gnatmq